# Libgdx - Colouring only part of a sprite dynamically

Tags: java, android, libgdx, blending, spritebatch

Have an Android application running Libgdx with many sprites all floating around. Currently I colour them all differently depending on which group they belong to, eg "red", "green", "blue" etc. However, I think I'd prefer to only colour part of the sprite instead of the whole thing.

Currently I use:

```
batch.begin();
batch.setColor(color1);
batch.draw(group1);
batch.setColor(color2);
batch.draw(group2);
etc..

batch.end();
```

`batch.setColor(color)` used to colour the batch and apply that to the whole sprite. When that group is done, I change the colour and move to the next group. I reset the batch colour when done with the groups.

Is there a shader/blender way of only colouring part of the sprite instead? For example, anything that's coloured **red** in my texture should be treated as a "dynamic area" that can then be coloured to whatever I dynamically set.

I can't use transparency as the edges of the textures are transparent and need to remain that way for blending.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using second `TextureRegion` in your `Sprite`. Thus you can use other color for this additional region. This other region should only contain part of the image which would change colors and transparent background.

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite {
    TextureRegion region1, region2;
    Color extraColor;

    ...

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(region1, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
                getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());

        batch.setColor(extraColor);
        batch.draw(region2, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),
                getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rara, thanks for getting back to me. Bit confused by your method. Currently the textureregion is the returned section of the atlas for the sprite I want to display, let's say the character. How would I go about colouring only a portion of this returned sprite? Are you creating different texture regions for each part of that character?

Comment: Yes. You should add another texture to your atlas at which visible only the part of your character for which your want to change color. Then create `MySprite` where `region1` is character texture and `region2` is this second texture.  Don't forget to set `extraColor` value before rendering.

Comment: That method seems like quite a lot of overhead though? I have a sprite which has been rotated in 8 directions, and each direction is animated with 4 frames. So I would need a texture region image in the atlas for each of those? Just seems like a lot of admin nightmare, especially if the main character graphic is updated. The sprites used have transparencies - is there no way to target a particular colour of the sprite, such as, Magenta, and only dynamically colour that part ? Like how a Green/Blue Screen works with tv/films

Comment: Well, you should include such details in question :) In that case I can recommend you to look at `Pixmap` class: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html . You can achieve what you want using `getColor()` and `drawPixel()` methods. I'm not sure that this is optimal solution but it should work.